# Out of multiple chkboxes, how to retrieve values assign with selected chkboxes (multiple select at a time)

Tags: php, html

Could really do with some help from anyone. Here's what I need to accomplish;

I am working on a form that has 6 checkboxes (each with its own value). Now, on clicking number of chkboxes at a time, on submitting the form, I want to retrieve values assign with that many chkboxes. User can select random checkboxes.

My Code:

Technologies:

```
                <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" value="1" /> Kingspan Solar</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" value="2" /> Solar PVT</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" value="3" /> Insulation</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" value="4" /> Gas boiler</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" value="5" /> Oil boiler</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" value="6" /> Heat recovery ventilation</br>
                <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Get The Info"></br>
                <?php
                    function IsChecked($chkname,$value)
                    {
                        if(!empty($_POST[$chkname]))
                        {
                            foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval)
                            {
                                if($chkval == $value)
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    $tech = $_POST['technologies'];
                    if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
                    {

                    // For Technology No. 1: Kingspan Solar 
                    if(IsChecked('technologies','1'))
                    {
                        if(IsChecked('technologies','2'))
                        {
                            if(IsChecked('technologies','3') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','4') )
                                {
                                    if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                                    {
                                        if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                        {
                                            echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation, 4. Gas Boiler, 5. Oil Boiler and 6.Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation, 4. Gas Boiler and 5. Oil Boiler are selected'; 
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                    {
                                        echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation, 4. Gas Boiler and 6.Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation and 4. Gas Boiler are selected';
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                                {
                                    if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                    {
                                        echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation, 5. Oil Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation and 5. Oil Boiler are selected';    
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT 3. Insulation are checked. ';
                                }
                            }
                            else if(IsChecked('technologies','4') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                                {
                                    if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                    {
                                        echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 4. Gas Boiler, 5. Oil Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 4. Gas Boiler and 5. Oil Boiler are selected';    
                                    }

                                }
                                else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 4. Gas Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 4. Gas Boiler are selected';
                                }
                            }
                            else if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT, 5. Oil Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT and 5. Oil Boiler are selected';   
                                }

                            }
                            else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar 2. Solar PVT is checked. ';
                            }

                        }
                        else if(IsChecked('technologies','3') )
                        {
                            if(IsChecked('technologies','4') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                                {
                                    if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                    {
                                        echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 3. insulation, 4. Gas Boiler, 5. Oil Boiler and 6.Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 3. insulation, 4. Gas Boiler and 5. Oil Boiler are selected';  
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 3. insulation 4. Gas Boiler and 6.Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 3. insulation and 4. Gas Boiler are selected';
                                }
                            }
                            else if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 3. insulation, 5. Oil Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 3. insulation and 5. Oil Boiler are selected'; 
                                }
                            }
                            else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar 3. Insulation and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar and 3. Insulation are checked. ';
                            }
                        }
                        else if(IsChecked('technologies','4') )
                        {
                            if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 4. Gas Boiler, 5. Oil Boiler and 6.Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 4. Gas Boiler and 5. Oil Boiler are selected'; 
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar and 4. Gas Boiler and 6.Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                            }
                        }
                        else if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                        {
                            if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar, 5. Oil Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar and 5. Oil Boiler are selected';    
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '1. Kingspan Solar is checked. ';
                            }
                        }
                    }

                        // For Technology No. 2: Solar PVT
                    else if(IsChecked('technologies','2'))
                    {
                        if(IsChecked('technologies','3') )
                        {
                            if(IsChecked('technologies','4') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                                {
                                    if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                    {
                                        echo '2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation, 4. Gas Boiler, 5. Oil Boiler and 6.Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo '2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation, 4. Gas Boiler and 5. Oil Boiler are selected';   
                                    }
                                }
                                else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation, 4. Gas Boiler and 6.Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation and 4. Gas Boiler are selected';
                                }
                            }
                            else if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation, 5. Oil Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation and 5. Oil Boiler are selected';  
                                }
                            }
                            else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                            {
                                echo '2. Solar PVT, 3. insulation and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '2. Solar PVT 3. Insulation are checked. ';
                            }
                        }
                        else if(IsChecked('technologies','4') )
                        {
                            if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                            {
                                if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                                {
                                    echo '2. Solar PVT, 4. Gas Boiler, 5. Oil Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo '2. Solar PVT, 4. Gas Boiler and 5. Oil Boiler are selected';  
                                }

                            }
                            else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                            {
                                echo '2. Solar PVT, 4. Gas Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '2. Solar PVT, 4. Gas Boiler are selected';
                            }
                        }
                        else if(IsChecked('technologies','5') )
                        {
                            if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                            {
                                echo '2. Solar PVT, 5. Oil Boiler and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '2. Solar PVT and 5. Oil Boiler are selected'; 
                            }

                        }
                        else if(IsChecked('technologies','6') )
                        {
                            echo '2. Solar PVT and 6. Heat recovery ventilation are selected';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '2. Solar PVT is checked. ';
                        }                           
                    }
```

Comment: Share your tried code please.

Comment: Sure , its easy but please post some code that you have worked on

Comment: Thank u guys for ur help. I am adding my code in the above explanation area. I am giving the code for first two chkboxes (bcoz same goes for the rest 4 chkboxes). Plz hav a look & help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same name to all checkbox like `testchkbox[]` and at the form submit you can retrieve the value of all the selected checkbox.

using `$chckvalues = $_POST['testchkbox'];`

Answer (score 0):

Name your checkbox like an array eg

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbname[]" value="value 1" /> Value 1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbname[]" value="value 2" /> Value 2 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbname[]" value="value 3" /> Value 3 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbname[]" value="value 4" /> Value 4 <br>
```

In PHP retrive value

```
 <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['cbname'])) 
    {
        $checkBoxArray = $_POST['cbname']; 

        //Comma seprated checkbox values as single string
        $checkBoxComma = implode(",", $checkBoxArray); 

       //Loop through values
        foreach ($checkBoxArray  as $value)
        {
          echo $value . "<br>";
        }

       //Print array
         print_r($checkBoxArray); 
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I have added my code in the explanation area of my question. Plz go through it & help me out....

Answer (score 0):

For more optimal code you can create list of availabe values and captions for it (in array or a source from DB). In this case you can use foreach for check and print user selections.

See code and try in at http://demos.webtricks.pro/so/selected-checkbox/

```
<?php
    // List of avaibale values
    $technologies = array (
        1 => "Kingspan Solar",
        "Solar PVT",
        "Insulation",
        "Gas boiler",
        "Oil boiler",
        "Heat recovery ventilation"
    );

?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <?php foreach ($technologies as $techId => $tech) : ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="technologies[]" value="<?php echo $techId;?>" /> <?php echo $tech;?><br/>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Get The Info"><br/>
            <?php
            // If 'technologies' is set int request - user click button
            if (isset($_REQUEST['technologies'])) {
                //$_REQUEST['technologies'] - array with selected checkboxes values
                $techs = $_REQUEST['technologies'];
                foreach ($techs as $techId) {
                    echo "{$techId}. {$technologies[$techId]}<br/>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```